# How to substitute values in a key-value file if keys exists in shell environment?

Tags: shell, sed, variable-substitution

I have a file like below with key value pair separated by `=`. I have already exported some variables to my shell. Now I want a shell script which can substitute the values for its corresponding keys if those keys are already exist in env variables or exported to shell.

I can have used envsubst but I didn't want to prefix a dollar symbol with those default values. If there is any other tool like envsubst which can help me substitute the string value please refer that also.

foo.yaml

```
PROJECT_NAME=test
DOMAIN_NAME=test.localhost
NETWORK_NAME=traefik-network    
ENVIRONMENT=dev
DRUPAL_VERSION=8
MYSQL_HOSTNAME=test.mariadb
MYSQL_DATABASE=drupal
MYSQL_USER=test
MYSQL_PASSWORD=pass
MYSQL_PORT=3306
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass
```

Comment: I don't know why It is getting negative vote. Isn't my question clear or is a very basic question ?

Comment: Pls consider accepting the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you are looking for something like below.

```
> cat foo.yaml
PROJECT_NAME=test
DOMAIN_NAME=test.localhost
NETWORK_NAME=traefik-network
ENVIRONMENT=dev
DRUPAL_VERSION=8
MYSQL_HOSTNAME=test.mariadb
MYSQL_DATABASE=drupal
MYSQL_USER=test
MYSQL_PASSWORD=pass
MYSQL_PORT=3306
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass
>
> export ENVIRONMENT=sit
> export DRUPAL_VERSION=10
> export MYSQL_PASSWORD="*****"
>
> perl -lpe ' s/(.*)=(.*)/sprintf("%s=%s","$1",$ENV{$1}? $ENV{$1}:$2)/ge ' foo.yaml
PROJECT_NAME=test
DOMAIN_NAME=test.localhost
NETWORK_NAME=traefik-network
ENVIRONMENT=sit
DRUPAL_VERSION=10
MYSQL_HOSTNAME=test.mariadb
MYSQL_DATABASE=drupal
MYSQL_USER=test
MYSQL_PASSWORD=*****
MYSQL_PORT=3306
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass
>
```

Does this help?.

Note that you can use -i switch in Perl to overwrite the file if you have write permissions

```
> perl -i -lpe ' s/(.*)=(.*)/sprintf("%s=%s","$1",$ENV{$1}? $ENV{$1}:$2)/ge ' foo.yaml
> cat foo.yaml
PROJECT_NAME=test
DOMAIN_NAME=test.localhost
NETWORK_NAME=traefik-network
ENVIRONMENT=sit
DRUPAL_VERSION=10
MYSQL_HOSTNAME=test.mariadb
MYSQL_DATABASE=drupal
MYSQL_USER=test
MYSQL_PASSWORD=*****
MYSQL_PORT=3306
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass
>
```

AWK solultion.

```
> awk -F"=" ' { $2=ENVIRON[$1]?ENVIRON[$1]:$2; printf("%s=%s\n",$1,$2) } ' foo.yaml
```

can be further shortened as

```
> awk -F"=" ' { printf("%s=%s\n",$1,ENVIRON[$1]?ENVIRON[$1]:$2) } ' foo.yaml
```

Handling blank lines

```
> awk -F"=" ' { if (!/^\s*$/) $0=sprintf("%s=%s",$1,ENVIRON[$1]?ENVIRON[$1]:$2) }1 ' foo.yaml
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the efforts to help me.  I wanted inplace edit that your second answer solves. Can you do the same in awk and sed also?

Comment: added awk solution.. redirect it to another file and rename to original file..pls check

Comment: I will surely accept it as answer. How ever the awk one adds one `=` in blank line

Comment: the blank line issue with awk has been fixed.. check the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you. awk solution is still needs some changing. It postpend an equal symbol on comment line. like `# General config=`